# How can my React app use boot strap classNames when I do not see bootstrap mentioned anywhere in the project?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have searched the entire project for 'bootstrap' but no results, but I am able to use things like 
`<h2 className="text-primary">{name}s Bio</h2>`, how am I able to use this? 
Is bootstrap apart of the project by default? This is my package.json file...

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Comment: Check the `index.html` for an included stylesheet

Comment: No, it should not be included by default. Although it is not in your package.json file could it be that you imported it from a CDN through your index.html file? I created a new react project and try applying the "text-primary" class and do not see the bootstrap styling. Could it be that you also have defined that class name and its styling some where else? Perhaps you could try using more obsure bootstrap components to test to see if bootstrap is configured on your project correctly.

Comment: In vscode use control + shift + f to search all files in your project. I'm sure bootstrap is in there somewhere.

Comment: I tried control + shift + f and no results

Comment: There is a link I have in my project that I guess is where the bootstrap is coming from. I commented it on answer to the question, but does anyone know where the link came from? Does create react app add that link to index.html?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap and other libraries can also be added through `index.html` file as a CDN so you can check in the header if it is included.

Comment: I have this in my index.html so maybe this is it? `      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
` ? I don't remember adding this myself. When I use 'create react app', do you think that it was added in then?

Comment: yes its the reason.you could have not added this yourself ,it is possible that it was already there from whichever source you have got your code.I would recommend using  [`react-bootstrap`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)

Comment: I was following a Udemy course but I do not remember ever copying and pasting any code at all. I typed it all, and I have never seen that link before. So I can’t figure out how I got the link. What does index.html look like when using create react app?

Comment: dont worry ,now you know how to deal with such problem.